# Как перебрать значение свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Собираю карту. Использую [этот скрипт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list).Есть массив с адресами.

```
var addr = '["Москва, Кирова, д. 6", "Орел, Ленина, д. 3"]';
addr = JSON.parse(addr);

addr[0] // "Москва, Кирова, д. 6";
addr[1] // "Орел, Ленина, д. 3";
```

Нужно вывести эти адреса на карту. Т.е. `addr[0]`, `addr[1]` и т.д. подставлять в значения свойства объекта.
Просто так перебрать св-ва объекта не получается.

```
for (i=0; i<addr.length; i++) {
    var groups = [
        {
            name: "Парки",
            style: "islands#redIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    name: addr[i];
                }
            ]},
    ]};
```

и как при этом получить значение св-ва? `groups[items]` не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var addr = '["Москва, Кирова, д. 6", "Орел, Ленина, д. 3"]';
addr = JSON.parse(addr);
console.log(addr)
var groups = [];
for (i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {
  groups.push({
    name: "Парки",
    style: "islands#redIcon",
    items: [{
      name: addr[i]
    }]
  })
};

console.log(groups[0].items)
```